# Populate the column based on the criteria in R

Tags: r

I am trying to populate a column with the place names (say city names like San Francisco, San Jose...) based on the conditions of the multiple columns containing attendance to certain events in R programming.

For example, my data (called df) would look like this:

```
Name     question1        question2        question3      question4    CityName
A           Y                Y                N              N   
B           N                N                N              N
C           Y                N                Y              Y
```

I want to have a city name column populated on the condition that if the person answers Y on either question 1 or 2, the city name would be "San Francisco" and if the person answers N on both, the city name would be "San Jose."

So, the final result would be like this:

```
Name     question1        question2        question3      question4     CityName
A           Y                Y                N              N         San Francisco
B           N                N                N              N         San Jose
C           Y                N                Y              Y         San Francisco
```

I do not know how to populate the column with characters like "San Francisco" when there is a condition (in this case conditions) like the code below, which will populate the column CityName with TRUE or FALSE.

```
df <-mutate[df, CityName = (question1 == "Y")]
```

I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to check for multiple conditions and assign output accordingly. This would be easy to expand if you have more conditions to check later.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(City_Name = case_when(
     question1 == "Y" | question2 == "Y" ~ "San Francisco", 
     question1 == "N" & question2 == "N" ~ "San Jose",
     TRUE ~ NA_character_))


#  Name question1 question2 question3 question4     City_Name
#1    A         Y         Y         N         N San Francisco
#2    B         N         N         N         N      San Jose
#3    C         Y         N         Y         Y San Francisco
```